# SSIS and SSRS in the same solution explorer 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and I want my SSRS report and MY SSIS package to be on the same solution explorer window. 
See attached picture.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For having several project in the same solution do the below steps:

At first you need to create a blank solution. As is written in [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141011(v=sql.90).aspx) you should do below steps :

To create a blank solution:

1. Open Business Intelligence Development Studio.
2. On the File menu, point to Add, and then click New Project.

[image]

3. In the New Project dialog box, expand Other Project Types, and then click
4. Visual Studio Solutions.

[image]

5. In the Templates pane, click Blank Solution.

[image]

6. Optionally, edit the solution name and location.
7. Optionally, click Browse to specify a different location for the solution.
8. If source control software is installed on the local computer, optionally
9. select Add to Source Control.
10. Click OK.

Then you can create the first project.

[image]

Do right click on you solution

[image]

Select you project type

[image]

And you can add the second project by right clicking on your project :

[image]

Select the type of your project.

[image]

You can ADD more project to this solution IF you want.

you will have something like that

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a solution on the top level and create an SSIS project and SSRS project if you would like to have two different projects.

If not just add a new item - SSRS report, in the SSIS project